# Please add [ie-mobile] and [pocket-ie] as synonyms of [internet-explorer]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I recently suggested two [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/internet-explorer/synonyms) for [internet-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer): [ie-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie-mobile) and [pocket-ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pocket-ie). The latter two tags are wiki-less, little used (50 tagged questions, *combined*), and somewhat defunct. However, it seems not enough users have sufficient score to vote up the [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/internet-explorer/synonyms).

Please create the synonyms.

Comment: Are you sure just retagging isn't a more appropriate action? And that they actually mean the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

If [mobile-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-safari) can exist separately from [safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safari) by virtue of being a mobile version of the browser, I don't see why [ie-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie-mobile) can't be independent of [internet-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer).

As for [pocket-ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pocket-ie), I'm a little unsure if I should synonymize with [ie-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie-mobile). On one hand, it's just the old name for what is really the same product. On the other hand, it's a very specific version for very specific platforms (Pocket PC, Windows CE). Perhaps it could be synonymized, and questions about that specific version could simply include the platform tag ([pocketpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pocketpc), [windows-ce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-ce) respectively).

Comment: What do you think about [tag:mobile-chrome]?

Comment: @Mooseman: Likewise.

Comment: @Mooseman: A better question to ask, and one I'd like to know the answer to myself, is: is the distinction between "browser X" and "mobile browser X" meaningful beyond the product name? That will help us decide whether these tags should be synonymized.

Comment: re: last comment: IMO, the only thing that changes is addons available (be it, plugins, codecs, etc.), supported functions (lately most browsers desktop-mobile pair support the same things, ex. [IE](http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie%2B11%2Cie_mob%2B11), [Chrome](http://caniuse.com/#compare=chrome%2B39%2Cchrome%2B40%2Cand_chr%2B39) and [Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#compare=firefox%2B35%2Cand_ff%2B33) (check mixed support header)), touch events (not really) and available screen size. We might want to compare the same questions with both tags and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Braiam: Some platforms like iOS are strict on what rendering engines third-party browsers can use. IIRC, Chrome on iOS uses the same engine as Safari for this reason.

Comment: I feel that [mobile-browserName] is about as useful as [css3] or [html5]. The platform (e.g., [windows-phone-8] or [android-5.0-lollipop])